# Symfony 3 - CKEditor does not save correctly in the database

Tags: database, symfony, ckeditor

I have a very strange problem with CKEditor on Symfony 3.4
When I create a new line in my database, via the CKEditor utility, I write everything I want, I make the layout, I add images. Everything is OK.

But when I validate, to save the HTML format of what I typed, in my database, it happens that it does not record everything.

Either he takes away text, images, or both.

And I have this since I configured the bundle FOSUserBundle.

**I write my text**

[image]

**I check the source code**

[image]

**I look at what has been saved in the database**

[image]

**And the rendering on my site**
[image]

Comment: What column type is that (minuscule)? My french isn't any good, but it looks like something "tiny". Could be that the text gets too long and doesn't fit.

Comment: This is the "Content" column. However, I doubt that it comes from the size of the text because on another version of my site in which I did not implement the bundle FOSUser, everything works perfectly well, whatever the size :/

Comment: Do you knwo what `minuscule` type does ? It really sound like a "tiny text" there. Did you try to change it for `text` type ? If you are sure it's not that, did you track the text through your code, like dump it just before set it in Entity, just before save/flush it, etc ? to check if it's good before the save.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! Indeed it was that! It's very strange because I did a copy / paste of my old database, and it seems that the format of the field has changed. Very strange, but now it works, thank you!